# Running Ionic App in the Memu emulator not work properly

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator, adb, ionic4

I'm trying to run an `Ionic` project to the Memu `emulator`, I have been connected the **emulator to the Android studio** with this comment

```
    adb connect localhost:21503
```

And after running the project with this comment

```
   ionic cordova run android -l
```

It runs successfully in the `emulator`, but the problem is after opening the app in the `emulator` I got the error below

#### Application Error

> The connection to the server was unsuccessfully.
>   (http://localhost:8100)

[image: Image error]

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on an actual android phone and see if it is just an emulator error. If it is an emulator error delete the emulator and re-install it.